# SML/NJ Asked to modify my code to use fldr, fldl and map

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I'm asked to modify the code I wrote such that in most of the functions I have to use either `fldr or fldl`

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/njlmsgu950y9nja/project.pdf) is the description which includes the test cases.

I'm wondering it would be great if you can give me some hint where I should modify to use those functions.

Due to lack of documentations and examples in ML I had to ask this question here

Thank you.

```
fun is_member [] x = false |
is_member (h::t) x = if (h=x) then true else is_member t x;


fun splitter string = 
let
fun remove_c [] = [] |
remove_c (h::t) = (String.tokens (fn c => c = #":") h) @ (remove_c t)
fun remove_ex [] = [] |
remove_ex (h::t) = remove_c((String.tokens (fn c => c = #"!") h)) @ (remove_ex t)
fun remove_q [] = [] |
remove_q (h::t) = remove_ex((String.tokens (fn c => c = #"?") h)) @ (remove_q t)
fun remove_sc [] = [] |
remove_sc (h::t) = remove_q((String.tokens (fn c => c = #";") h)) @ (remove_sc t)
fun remove_dot [] = [] |
remove_dot (h::t) = remove_sc((String.tokens (fn c => c = #".") h)) @ (remove_dot t)
fun remove_nl [] = [] |
remove_nl (h::t) = remove_dot((String.tokens (fn c => c = #"\n") h)) @ (remove_nl t)
fun remove_tabs [] = [] |
remove_tabs (h::t) = remove_nl((String.tokens (fn c => c = #"\t") h)) @ (remove_tabs t)
fun remove_commas [] = [] |
remove_commas (h::t) = remove_tabs((String.tokens (fn c => c = #",") h)) @ (remove_commas t)
in
remove_commas((String.tokens (fn c => c = #" ") string))
end;

val stop_words = "a,able,about,across,after,all,almost,also,am,among,an,and,any,are,as,at,be,because,been,but,by,can,cannot,could,dear,did,do,does,either,else,ever,every,for,from,get,got,had,has,have,he,her,hers,him,his,how,however,i,if,in,into,is,it,its,just,least,let,like,likely,may,me,might,most,must,my,neither,no,nor,not,of,off,often,on,only,or,other,our,own,rather,said,say,says,she,should,since,so,some,than,that,the,their,them,then,there,these,they,this,tis,to,too,twas,us,wants,was,we,were,what,when,where,which,while,who,whom,why,will,with,would,yet,you,your";

val stop_word_list = splitter stop_words;

fun is_stop_word string = 
let
fun f L = map (fn x => (is_member stop_word_list x)) L
in
f (splitter string)
end;


fun get_stop_words string = 
let
fun get_stop [] x = x |
get_stop (h::t) x = if((is_member stop_word_list h = true) andalso ((is_member t h) = false)) then (get_stop t [h]@x) else (get_stop t x);
in
get_stop (splitter string) []
end;


fun remove_stop_words string = 
let
fun remove_stop [] = [] |
remove_stop (h::t) = if(is_member stop_word_list h = true) then (remove_stop t) else [h]@(remove_stop t)
in
remove_stop(splitter string)
end;
```

Comment: I must add that the code above works fine, but I need to modify it such that it uses those functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to first understand how foldl and foldr work, once you have that you can apply the logic from your existing code to the functions.

`foldl(fn (a,b) => (*expression*)) *initial condition* *list*;`

So foldl(or foldr) takes a function as the first parameter. You can use some sml defined function like `op >` or `op +` but often these more simple functions don't do the job that you want them to do.

The alternative is to write your own anonymous function and pass it as a parameter such as in the example above. In addition to the function, `foldl` takes two more arguments being the initial condition and the list.

`foldl` then looks at the indexes of the list and using the initial condition, applies that index to the function. In the case of my example, `a` is the list index being passed to the function by `foldl` and `b` is the result of the expression for the first call (first index).

`foldl` will continue to do this for the remainder of the list, passing each index to `a` and the result of each call to the function in `b`.

So using `a`, you can really perform any computation you want and make any comparisons that you want using `b`.

I don't really want to give you code but here is the setup for is_member.

```
fun is_member list x = foldl(fn (a,b) => (if *expression* then *some result* else *some other result*)) *initial condition* list;
```

You will need to use a,b, and x in your comparison and in your return. Since this is a boolean return, your initial condition should either be true or false. Good luck.